# Parameter file for the mapping having two target table in different schema-informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have defined all the properties in parameter file.

The properties tab in session level properties allows one connection string to specify but i have two target tables in different schema.

If i specify any one connection variable in the target connection its showing error stating that value not specified for other target table connection.

Can anyone help me pls.

Comment: Not very clear where you are facing problem. Are your tables in different databases or in different schema in the same database?

Comment: different schema but same database

Comment: Then you can create two seperate parameters for the schema names. Is that what you did?

Comment: I created two parameters and placed it in file and added those in mappings tab of session.how to add these two parameters in the properties tab-->$Target connection value

Comment: ok. Can you share the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Missing initial value for the session parameter '$DBconnect_target1'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75824/discussion-between-samik-and-infa).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving the target connection in front of  '$Target connection value' in Properties tab of the session, you can put both of your connections in two different variables in parameter file and then can specify the respective variable in Mapping tab of the session at respective Connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can always specify different connection detials for different targets in Mapping Tab. 

Go to Mapping tab-> choose your Target and in connections Pane you can choose existing connection or specify new conneciton parameter.